# iOS: Check if "Darken Colours" is activated

Tags: ios, uicolor

Starting in iOS 7.1, Apple added a new feature called "Darken Colours" that, as it is expectable by the name darkens down the colour od UI-elements (Bar Button items, etc.)
Now, I'd like to darken down some other UI-elements in my app if the user has activated this feature.
Is there a possibility to check programmatically if this feature is enabled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iOS 8 SDK, Apple added several functions for detecting whether Accessibility options are enabled. ([UIKit Function Reference: Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW39))

Among them is one called `UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled`

Swift:

```
func UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled() -> Bool
```

Objective-C:

```
BOOL UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled ( void );
```